# Windows, apache, https

Tags: apache-2.2

In my hostfile (Windows) I have this:

```
127.0.0.1 testsite.hu
```

in my apache config, I have:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:\work"
  ServerName testsite.hu
  <Directory "C:\work">
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.php
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    DirectoryIndex index.html
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

this all works well if I call:

```
testsite.hu
www.testsite.hu
http://www.testsite.hu
```

but unfortunatly when I call as https:

```
https://testsite.hu
```

Firefox says she can't open it. Why? I have no idea what to do with Apache

Comment: Your VirtualHost is listening on port 80. HTTPS listens on port 443.

Comment: oh, right, and what to do? :S

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html